# Patch .NET app to run hidden (splash screen/main window) using Reflector/Reflexil

Tags: .net, patch, reflector, reflexil

im trying to modify a program to run hidden, no splash screen and no window (it's a free app for canon cameras to receive images over wifi).

i use for live slideshow, but every time the camera reconnects, the program is launched and the splash screen and app windows is put in front of the slideshow. the programs needs no interaction, just run in the background. (it's the program that receive the images, it needs to be running)

i'm a bit familiar with basic patching with ollydbg, but as this is a .net app, it's way over my head.

i tried using apps that patch on launch STARTUPINFO to make the app window hidden, but the splash screen is still shown, and as the program is controlled via another one that detects the camera and launch it with appropriate parameters, it needs to run hidden "on it's own"

Reflector/Reflexil seems powerful enough to be able to do what i need, but i just don't know enough to find what function/call/parameter to make the whole app hidden.

if anyone can point me in the right direction... thanks in advance!

OBS: file, in case anyone want to take a look: http://www111.zippyshare.com/v/gMvozk1h/file.html

Comment: If you are running Win 10, have you tried creating a secondary Desktop (WinKey-Tab -> New Desktop) and run the program on that Desktop?  That would be a simple solution if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is preventing EOS Utility from automatically launching when you connect your camera to your PC, reverse engineering and modifying the IL code sounds like massive overkill.

Try googling for **"canon camera disable EOS Utility autostart"** or something along those lines.

Comment: No no, this IS the program that transfers the images. it's needed to receive images from camera. my point is to make it run "silently" with no windows

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, removing Show() functions disabled the windows from showing. problem solved ;)